# Flatten IEnumerable<IEnumerable<>>; understanding generics

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable, nested-generics

I wrote this extension method (which compiles):

```
public static IEnumerable<J> Flatten<T, J>(this IEnumerable<T> @this) 
                                           where T : IEnumerable<J>
{
    foreach (T t in @this)
        foreach (J j in t)
            yield return j;
}
```

The code below causes a compile time error (no suitable method found), **why?**:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> foo = new int[2][];
var bar = foo.Flatten();
```

If I implement the extension like below, I get no compile time error:

```
public static IEnumerable<J> Flatten<J>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<J>> @this)
{
    foreach (IEnumerable<J> js in @this)
        foreach (J j in js)
            yield return j;
}
```

**Edit(2)**: This question I consider answered, but it raised another question regarding overload resolution and type constraints. This question I put here: [Why aren't type constraints part of the method signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440888)

Comment: Your edit doesn't work because you have too many surrounding enumerable. `foo.Flatten<IEnumerable<int>, int>();` should work.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

First, you don't need `Flatten()`; that method already exists, and is called `SelectMany()`. You can use it like this:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> foo = new [] { new[] {1, 2}, new[] {3, 4} };
var bar = foo.SelectMany(x => x); // bar is {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Second, your first attempt doesn't work because generic type inference works only based on the arguments to the method, not generic constraints associated with the method. Since there is no argument that directly uses the `J` generic parameter, the type inference engine can't guess what `J` should be, and thus doesn't think that your method is a candidate.

It's edifying to see how `SelectMany()` gets around this: it requires an additional `Func<TSource, TResult>` argument. That allows the type inference engine to determine both generic types, since they are both available based solely on the arguments provided to the method.

Comment: @Daryl: Because it should be `Flatten<IEnumerable<int>,int>(foo)`

Comment: @Daryl Generic constraints are not considered part of a method signature; for *way more*, see this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx

Comment: @Daryl: Don't - there is definitely a learning curve here, this is by far not the easiest aspect of C# to understand. Just trying to master it puts you ahead of 95% of the rest already ;-)

Comment: I have written something like that `Flatten` method for various projects in the course of the past years, and I've always called it `Flatten` as well. Even now that I know it exists, I think that `SelectMany` is an incredibly misleading choice for the name of that method, as it is quite counterintuitive to assume that something called `SelectMany` would flatten a hierarchy. +1 for pointing out that it actually does.

Answer (score 21):

dlev's answer is fine; I just thought I'd add a little more information.

Specifically, I note that you are attempting to use generics to implement a sort of covariance on `IEnumerable<T>`. **In C# 4 and above, `IEnumerable<T>` already is covariant.**

Your second example illustrates this. If you have

```
List<List<int>> lists = whatever;
foreach(int x in lists.Flatten()) { ... }
```

then type inference will reason that `List<List<int>>` is convertible to `IE<List<int>>`, `List<int>` is convertible to `IE<int>`, and therefore, because of covariance, `IE<List<int>>` is convertible to `IE<IE<int>>`. That gives type inference something to go on; it can infer that T is int, and everything is good.

This doesn't work in C# 3. Life is a bit harder in a world without covariance but you can get by with judicious use of the `Cast<T>` extension method.