# F# member overload with generic constraints

Tags: f#

Is it possible to do a member overload with generic constraints? Here, I am trying to create and `AddWithOption` method to support both value types and reference types. If you look at [the gist](https://gist.github.com/ctaggart/0c692d42b3bb8c19e229), I show several attempts to make this happen.

[image]

My workaround was simply to not overload the member. I renamed with one for value types to `AddWithOptionValue`. However, it would be cool if the overload worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Also not the best code example. A better implementation is: `member x.AddWithOption (nm, op:Option<_>) = if op.IsSome then x.AddWithValue (nm, op.Value) else x.AddWithValue (nm, DBNull.Value)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Constraints are not part of method signature (per **ECMA 335, I.8.6.1.5 Method signatures**) meaning that in CIL you cannot have two methods which signatures differ only in constraints. In order to encode such signatures in CIL one need to use optional or required modifiers but this is not very trivial and today F# does not do that.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. I read more on [Why aren't type constraints part of the method signature?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440888/why-arent-type-constraints-part-of-the-method-signature) and it helped.