# Why can two differently specified generics not exist in the same namespace in c#?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create a function that either returns the first element in an enumerable or the appropriate type of null. I would think class and struct are disjoint, but these two functions can't seem to exist in the same namespace. Why?

```
static T? TryFirst<T>(IEnumerable<T> b) where T : struct
{
    return b.Any() ? b.First() : new T?();
}
static T TryFirst<T>(IEnumerable<T> b) where T : class
{
    return b.Any() ? b.First() : null;
}
```

Comment: same name, same arguments

Comment: but different and disjoint type constraints, I can happily do this and more in C++

Comment: C# isn't C++, and generics aren't templates. The `class` / `struct` type differentiation works only for top-level arguments, not for type parameters further embedded. As a *general* rule, type constraints do not influence overload resolution.

Comment: This seems to be the same as `IEnumerable<T>.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @phuzi: I thought so as well initially, but that's not true -- `IEnumerable<int>.FirstOrDefault` is `0`, not `(int?) null`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ah, you seem to be correct, thinking about it a little more, it makes sense.

Comment: This might be the answer you are looking for, check it out https://stackoverflow.com/a/9449918/920557.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It's because compiler will not be able to differentiate them.

You're creating same functions with same arguments.
`where` statement only states what generic types you can pass into this function but function definition itself is still the same for the compiler.

I recommend doing this:

```
static T? TryFirstStruct<T>(IEnumerable<T> b) where T : struct
{
    return b.Any() ? b.First() : new T?();
}

static T TryFirstObject<T>(IEnumerable<T> b) where T : class
{
    return b.Any() ? b.First() : null;
}
```

Also, if compiler would allow this behavior then programmer who's using your code next is going to get two same functions that receive and return same things.

Problems are:

- Your colleague will be pretty confused about it.
- When you'll use `var` keyword it will not be able to understand what value is going to be returned back to you.
- You'll have to use `dynamic` keyword and check type by yourself. Therefore you'll increase your code by a few times, slow down methods and generally make it unreadable.