# How to use Union with different type of collections?

Tags: c#, linq

My method will need to return a collection that contains `settings.AgentIds` and `agent ids` that correspond to `settings.LabelIds`. So I decided to use `Union`

```
IEnumerable<IAgentsGroup> labelGroups = _agentsGroups.Values.Where(x => settings.LabelIds.Contains(x.Id));

IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Guid>> labelAgentIds = labelGroups.Select(x => x.AgentIds);

return labelAgentIds.Union(settings.AgentIds);
```

But I dont now how to combine it into the one `Collection<Guid>`,

beacuse `settings.AgentIds` has type `Collection<Guid>` and `labelAgentIds` has `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Guid>>` type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flatten IEnumerable<IEnumerable<>>; understanding generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440497/flatten-ienumerableienumerable-understanding-generics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're content to just flatten the `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Guid>>` into an `IEnumerable<Guid>` in the obvious way, then [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336) is your friend:

```
IEnumerable<Guid> labelAgentIds = labelGroups.SelectMany(x => x.AgentIds);
return labelAgentIds.Union(settings.AgentIds);
```

Whereas `Select` maps each single element in the input to another single element in the output, `SelectMany` maps each single element in the input to *any number* of elements in the output (maybe 0, maybe 1, maybe more).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten the collection:

```
IEnumerable<Guid> labelAgentIds = labelGroups.SelectMany(x => x.AgentIds);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to flatten the `IEnumerable<Collection<Guid>>`, then use `SerlectMany`:

```
var allGuids = labelAgentIds.SelectMany(col => col).Union(settings.AgentIds);
Collection<Guid> result = new Collection<Guid>(allGuids.ToList());
```